# doubt in inequality measure theory: double sum and integral

Tags: measure-theory, ergodic-theory

Let $(M, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ to be a measure space, and $f: M\to M$ measurable function, and $\mu$ a finite invariant measure. 
If $\varphi: M \to \mathcal{R}$ is integrable then $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{\varphi(f^{n}(x))}{n} = 0$,   $\mu-a.e. x \in M$

proof:

Fix $\varepsilon > 0$. Define $E_{n} = \{ x\in M | |\varphi(f^{n}(x))| \geq n \varepsilon \}$. So,

$\mu (E_{n}) = \mu(\{ x\in M | |\varphi(x)| \geq n \varepsilon \})= \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \mu \{ x\in M | k \leq \frac{|\varphi(x)|}{\varepsilon} <  k+1    \}$. We obtain that:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu (E_{n})  = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \mu \{ x\in M | k \leq \frac{|\varphi(x)|}{\varepsilon} <  k+1    \}=$

$=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k \mu \{ x\in M | k \leq \frac{|\varphi(x)|}{\varepsilon} <  k+1    \} $.

But $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k \mu \{ x\in M | k \leq \frac{|\varphi(x)|}{\varepsilon} <  k+1    \} \leq \int \frac{|\varphi|}{\varepsilon}d\mu $  (*),

and $\varphi: M \to \mathcal{R}$ is integrable, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu (E_{n}) < \infty$. By Borel-Cantelli, we have done.

---

This proof can be found in  [ON  THE  SUBADDITIVE  ERGODIC  THEOREM, AVILA & BOCHI](http://www.mat.uc.cl/~jairo.bochi/docs/kingbirk.pdf), Lemma 2.

How can I show this inequality:

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k \mu \{ x\in M | k \leq \frac{|\varphi(x)|}{\varepsilon} <  k+1    \} \leq \int \frac{|\varphi|}{\varepsilon}d\mu $  ?

Thanks

Comment: This just follows from the definition of the lebesgue integral, you have approximated $\frac{|\phi(x)|}{\varepsilon} $ by a step function from below.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't see it. Do you have some reference that I can read something like this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f \geq 0$ be a measurable function, then

$$k \cdot \mu \left( \left\{x; k \leq f(x) < k+1 \right\} \right) =  \int 1_{[k,k+1)}(f(x)) \cdot \underbrace{k}_{\leq f(x)} \, \mu(dx) \leq \int 1_{[k,k+1)}(f(x)) \cdot f(x) \, \mu(dx).$$

Summing over $k \geq 1$ we obtain

$$\sum_{k \geq 1} k \mu \left( \left\{x; k \leq f(x) < k+1 \right\} \right) \leq \int f(x) \, \mu(dx).$$

Applying this inequality for $f(x) := |\varphi(x)|/\epsilon$ proves the desired inequality.